# What are the units of Odometry/orientation.z/w and Twist.angular.z fields?

Tags: navigation, odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I an new to ROS and am trying to understand the units in which the values in the Odometry.orientation.w and z fields and what do they represent. I am trying to rotate a turtlebot by a specific number of degrees. Is there a way to achieve it as I am able to set only angular velocities and whose unit I don't know either.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227851/what-are-the-units-of-odometry/orientation.z/w-and-twist.angular.z-fields?/) by [fayazvf](https://answers.ros.org/users/25788/fayazvf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-03-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Orientation is in terms of Quaternion, not Euler angles. You can check http://answers.ros.org/question/220333/what-do-x-y-and-z-denote-in-mavros-topic-mavrosimudata_raw/#220356

For unit conventions you can check [REP-0103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html#units). As you can check, angular velocity is rad/s if the code you use is convenient with REP-0103.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The orientation in ROS is (mostly) displayed as a [quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion). As such, it does not really have any units.
You can, however, derive an angular representation (e.g. roll/pitch/yaw) from this, using one of the [Rotation Methods](http://wiki.ros.org/geometry/RotationMethods), which then have `radians` as a unit.

- Python, from `nav_msgs/Odometry`, where `msg` is the full odometry msg:

  ```
    (roll, pitch, yaw) = tf.transformations.euler_from_quaternion([msg.pose.pose.orientation.x, msg.pose.pose.orientation.y, msg.pose.pose.orientation.z, msg.pose.pose.orientation.w])
  ```
- C++, from `nav_msgs/Odometry`, where `msg` is the full odometry msg:

  ```
    tf::Quaternion q(msg.pose.pose.orientation.x, msg.pose.pose.orientation.y, msg.pose.pose.orientation.z, msg.pose.pose.orientation.w);
    tf::Matrix3x3 m(q);
    double roll, pitch, yaw;
    m.getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
  ```

(There are several more ways to do this. If someone has more efficient ones, please share.)

The `Twist` has units of `m/s` for the `linear` terms, as well as `radian/s` for the `angular` terms.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fayazvf](https://answers.ros.org/users/25788/fayazvf/) on 2016-03-05**:
Thanks for the help.